# How to count white space in a string based on other string

Tags: c#

Suppose we have two string `s1` and `s2`

```
s1 = "123    456 789 012 1234";
s2 = "1234567";
```

I want to print `s2` with white space as given in string `s1` . Output will be

```
Output = "123   456 7";
```

Comment: Why would you need to count the whitespaces?

Comment: I want to print output with white space based on s2 length

Rand Random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach with simple `for` loop

```
string s1 = "123    456 789 012 1234";
string s2 = "1234567";

for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length && i < s2.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(s1[i]))
    {
        s2 = s2.Insert(i, s1[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/POn5E2

Comment: Most beautiful one for now

Comment: I thought the solution needs an equality check, so if s2 isn’t contained in s1 it wouldn’t insert whitespaces. eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/315OM5 shouldn’t output whitespaces

Comment: @RandRandom OP didn't mention the both strings have to be equal - imo this is only about transfering white space characters from `s1` to `s2`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `loop for s2` if the character equals s1 then add character to the result. Otherwise,until there add a space to result...

```
        string s1 = "123    456 789 012 1234";
        string s2 = "1234567";
        string result = "";

        int s1_index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s1[s1_index] == ' ')
                while (s1[s1_index] == ' ')
                {
                    result += ' ';
                    s1_index++;
                }

            if (s2[i] == s1[s1_index])
                result += s1[s1_index];

             s1_index++;
    }

   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I didn't vote down but this question is about white space characters, not just `' '`

Answer (score 0):

Simply just put a condition on number of non-whitespace characters. Not efficient solution, but it has a good idea:

```
string s1 = "123    456 789 012 1234";
string s2 = "1234567";
var s2Length = s2.Length;

var array = s1.TakeWhile((c, index) => s1.Substring(0, index + 1)
                                         .Count(f => !char.IsWhiteSpace(f)) <= s2Length)
              .ToArray();
var result = new string(array); //123    456 7
```